# Group terms in a large expression based on their minimum variable dependencies

Tags: algebra

Suppose I have a very large expression, `myEq[x1,x2,x3,x4]` in four variables, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4`.  (The general problem could of course use any number of variables.)  Some (constant) terms do not depend on any variables.  Some of the terms depend solely on `x1`, others solely on `x2`, ... some on both `x1` and `x2`, others on both `x1` and `x3`, .... and finally some on all four `x1` and `x2` and `x3` and `x4`.  There are, then, $2^4 = 16$ classes of terms based on their minimum variables.

I'd like to perform a four-variable (symbolic) integration of myEq, so I'd like to simplify the process by separating out all terms that depend just on `x1` and perform that integration over `x1`, and likewise for all the terms.

If the terms are all polynomial in the variables, then `Collect` might be useful.  As far as I can see, though, if I use `Collect[myEq, x1]` (say) I still get terms that involve joint terms, involving, say `x1` and `x2` as well as `x1` and `x3` and `x4`.  Moreover, I don't see how `Collect` is helpful for my problem of *non*-polynomial terms.

In short, what is the simplest way to take a complicated *non*-polynomial expression (e.g., trigonometric expression) and break it into parts that depend solely upon each variable and each conjunction of variables?

Minimal example:

```
myEq[x1,x2,x3,x4] = 5 + Cos[x1] + Sin[x1/2] + Tan[x2] + Cot[x1 x2] + Sin[x1 x2 x3] - Cos[x3] - Tan[x1/x3] + Sin[x2 + x3/x4] - Tan[x2 - x4] + Cot[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4] - Sin[x1 - x2 - x3/x4]
```

Break this into $2^4$ terms based on the minimum variables.

If there are $n$ variables, then break the expression into $2^n$ such terms.

Comment: maybe `GroupBy[List @@ myEq[x1, x2, x3, x4],  Variables[Level[#, {-1}]] &, Total]`?

Comment: Very nice... especially because it is short and yields sum of terms that depend upon the selected variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
group[expr_Plus] := Values@Reverse@KeySortBy[{Total@# &, # &}]@GroupBy[List @@ expr, Boole@Through[(FreeQ /@ {x4, x3, x2, x1})@#] &]

group[myEq[x1, x2, x3, x4]]
(* {{5}, {Cos[x1], Sin[x1/2]}, {Tan[x2]}, {-Cos[x3]}, {Cot[x1 x2]}, {-Tan[x1/x3]}, {-Tan[x2 - x4]}, {Sin[x1 x2 x3]}, {Sin[x2 + x3/x4]}, {Cot[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4], -Sin[x1 - x2 - x3/x4]}} *)
```

Essentially, we apply `FreeQ` to each variable/part combination to check whether that part depends on that variable. Doing this for each variable, we get a four long list of `True`/`False` for each part, which can be used for grouping. The rest is just some trickery to get the sorting right (if that's even needed).

Comment: Oh how very very elegant.  Perfect.  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 2):

```
groupByVariables = KeySort @ GroupBy[List @@ #, Variables @ Level[#, {-1}] &, Total] &;

groups = groupByVariables @ myEq[x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

> ```
> <|{} -> 5,
>  {x1} -> Cos[x1] + Sin[x1/2], 
>  {x2} -> Tan[x2], 
>  {x3} -> -Cos[x3], 
>  {x1, x2} -> Cot[x1 x2], 
>  {x1, x3} -> -Tan[x1/x3],
>  {x2, x4} -> -Tan[x2 - x4], 
>  {x1, x2, x3} -> Sin[x1 x2 x3], 
>  {x2, x3, x4} -> Sin[x2 + x3/x4], 
>  {x1, x2, x3, x4} -> Cot[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4] - Sin[x1 - x2 - x3/x4]|>
> ```

```
Graph[Join[Keys @ groups, Values @ groups], 
 KeyValueMap[DirectedEdge] @ groups, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 VertexCoordinates ->  Join @@ 
    (Thread[{#, Rescale @ Range @ Length @ Keys @ groups}]& /@ {1, 2}), 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed["Name", If[MemberQ[Keys @ groups, v], Before, After]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Also very valuable and elegant (+1).  (I'd expect no less...)